# Japanese film. Man is staying with a girl at house. Turns out he's Yakuza and protects her from his former bosses

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

I watched a lot of IFC and Sundance films when I was in highschool (around 2006/07ish). I vaguely remember watching this indie Japanese film, but it's ending has stuck with me. A quiet guy is our main protagonist. There are 2 sisters (I believe) that he encounters throughout the film. About halfway through one sister dies, and the protagonist and the other sister retreat to her somewhat abandoned house. The two start growing closer and begin to become attracted to each other. At one point she falls asleep on his lap and he has a wet dream, and has to wash his pants.

The part that I remember the most is the ending, in which a group of men break into the house attempting to kill one or both of them. The protagonist kills all of them, and removes his shirt... where we see that his back is covered in tattoos revealing that he was Yakuza.

I'm probably on a government watch list for all of the crazy google searches I've made recently trying to find this title. Please, help me.

Comment: *Sisterhood* from 2008 has a somewhat similar plot, but it's a bit obscure. See if you recognize anyone in [this poster](http://asianwiki.com/images/3/33/Sisterhood.jpg).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the one, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, dry that tear, smiley face; I got there eventually. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is actually [Last Life in the Universe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0345549/combined) from 2003, which I completely forgot about.

> A suicidal, obsessively compulsive Japanese librarian [Kenji] is forced to lie low in Thailand with a pot-smoking woman [Noi] coping with the recent loss of her sister.

Kenji has a wet dream when Noi naps on him, and turns out to have Yakuza tattoos on his back. And gangsters try to kill them in the end, but I'm not sure he kills them all, I think he just escapes. Shot by [Christopher Doyle](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0236313/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) (*In The Mood For Love*, *Hero*). Here's the trailer: